# Waiting until image finishes upload to fire code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am struggling to force code to be synchronous. The code is intended to upload an image using a vue composable, wait for the upload to succeed, then store the url from firebase storage into a database. The best I can do is get the code to function, but the success code fires before the upload is complete (though I get the url).

The code below does not work, but it's my attempt to try to chain the actions together using then callbacks to force them to behave in a synchronous manner. Not working.

VueComponent.vue

```
const newImage = async () => {
      if (image.value) {
        await uploadImage(image.value);
      } else return null;
    };

    const handleSubmit = async () => {
     
      try {
      
        const colRef = collection(db, "collection");

        newImage()
          .then(() => {
            addDoc(colRef, {
              content: content.value
            });
          })
          .then(() => {
            //code to run only on success
              });
          });
       
      } catch (error) {
       
      }
    };
```

useStorage.js composable

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import { projectStorage } from "../firebase/config";
import {
  uploadBytesResumable,
  getDownloadURL,
  ref as storageRef,
} from "@firebase/storage";

const useStorage = () => {
  const error = ref(null);
  const url = ref(null);
  const filePath = ref(null);

  const uploadImage = async (file) => {
    filePath.value = `${file.name}`;

    const storageReference = storageRef(projectStorage, 
 filePath.value);

  //<--I want this to be synchronous, but it isn't.
    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageReference, 
 file);

    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress =
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 
 100;
        console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
      },
      (err) => {
       
  
      },
      () => {
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) 
     => 
        {console.log("File available at", downloadURL);
      });
      }
    );
    
  };


  return { url, filePath, error, uploadImage };
};

export default useStorage;
```

Comment: "I am struggling to force code to be asynchronous." You said this multiple times by now, and: 1) you probably mean to force it to be *synchronous*, 2) making asynchronous code synchronous is not possible. It will always be asynchronous.

Comment: "does not work" and "not working" are really hard to help with. What *does* the code do when it runs? What did you expect it to do? If you set a breakpoint on every line and then run in the debugger, which is the *first* line that doesn't work as you expected it to.

Comment: Thank you, @FrankvanPuffelen. You're right, I means "synchronous." When handleSubmit fires, the newImage() function fires but does not wait for the uploadTask to complete, so it moves right into addDoc(). I would like uploadTask to complete before addDoc starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `uploadImage` doesn't wait for the upload to complete, so that's why the `addDoc` happens earlier than you want it to.

```
const uploadImage = async (file) => {
  filePath.value = `${file.name}`;

  const storageReference = storageRef(projectStorage, 
filePath.value);

  const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageReference, 
file);

  await uploadTask; //  Wait for the upload to finish

  const downloadURL = getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)

  return downloadURL;
}
```

Now you can call it with:

```
newImage()
  .then((downloadURL) => {
    addDoc(colRef, {
      content: content.value
    });
  })
```

Or, by using `await` again, with:

```
const downloadURL = await newImage();
addDoc(colRef, {
  content: content.value
});
```

Comment: As always, thank you very much! That worked. I will be using this code. I was getting tripped up because I was using uploadTask.on, and I was getting an error that it is not a function. I dropped the .on code, which is fine, and it works. I can't tell from the google docs why .on was resulting in that error.

Comment: Since you use `then()` in your calling code, you *must* return a promise from `newImage`, which you didn't do. You *can* use `on`, but you'll need to return your own promise in that case (`return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` and then call `resolve()` once you have the download URL.

Comment: Great stuff. Thank you very much for the time